# Running the LIVOX SDK2 on windows

Tags: visual-c++, sdk

Running quick_star on a Win system (with correctly configured congfig file) sometimes does not turn on radar sampling and keeps returning the following logs, what should I do to get the radar to start sampling and return point cloud data?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyA6r.jpg)

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead